# Access redux state value on a React + Redux + Hooks + Typescript web app

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-hooks, react-typescript

I am trying to access the redux state to display its value on my website. I am using React redux hooks with functional components and Typescript.

**Situation:**
I have a store with two reducers: UI and user. The initial state is:

```
{
  user: {
    authenticated: false,
    credentials: {}
  },
  UI: {
    loading: false,
    errors: null
  }
}
```

When the user signs in, the signinUser action takes place and correctly changes the redux state. For example, for an invalid signin, the redux state is:

```
{
  user: {
    authenticated: false,
    credentials: {}
  },
  UI: {
    loading: false,
    errors: {
      general: 'wrong credentials, please try again'
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem:**
I am trying to acces the UI.errors so I can display them on my website. i have a function in my Signin component thnamed submitForm that calls the signinUser action that correctly dispatches the actions. My problem is that after that I want to retrieve the state.ui.errors and I can't figure out how to.

I have tried all this:

- `componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) { ... }`  this solution is for class components and I am using functional components
- `useSelector((state: StoreState) => state.UI);` If I do it inside submitForm is invalid because React Hooks don't allow to call inside a function. If I do it outside, it fetches the old state.

Here are my files (the parts related to this issue)

store.tsx

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// Reducers
import userReducer from './reducers/userReducer';
import uiReducer from './reducers/uiReducer';

const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];

const reducers = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  UI: uiReducer
});

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
      (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);
export default store;
```

userActions.tsx

```
import { SET_USER, SET_ERRORS, CLEAR_ERRORS, LOADING_UI } from '../types';
import axios from 'axios';

// Interfaces
import { ISigninForm } from '../../utils/types';

// Redux
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

export const signinUser = (
  userData: ISigninForm,
  dispatch: Dispatch,
  handleDialogClose: () => void
) => {
  console.log('signinuser in userActions');
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_UI });
  axios
    .post('/signin', userData)
    .then((res) => {
      const FBIdToken = `Bearer ${res.data.token}`;
      localStorage.setItem('FBIdToken', FBIdToken);
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = FBIdToken;
      getUserData(dispatch);
      dispatch({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS });
      handleDialogClose();
      // history.push("/profile");   // this will redirect to a page not built yet
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      });
    });
};

export const getUserData = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  console.log('getUserData');
  axios
    .get('/user')
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('/user', res);
      dispatch({
        type: SET_USER,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log('err', err));
};
```

uiReducer.tsx

```
import { SET_ERRORS, CLEAR_ERRORS, LOADING_UI, IAction } from '../types';

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  errors: null
};

export default function (state = initialState, action: IAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        errors: action.payload
      };
    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        errors: null
      };
    case LOADING_UI:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

userReducer.tsx

```
import {
  SET_USER,
  SET_AUTHENTICATED,
  SET_UNAUTHENTICATED,
  IAction
} from '../types';

const initialState = {
  authenticated: false,
  credentials: {}
};

export default function (state = initialState, action: IAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_AUTHENTICATED:
      return {
        ...state,
        authenticated: true
      };
    case SET_UNAUTHENTICATED:
      return initialState;
    case SET_USER:
      console.log('SET_USER', action);
      return {
        authenticated: true,
        ...action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Signin.tsx

```
function Signin({ history }: RouteComponentProps): JSX.Element {
  // States
  const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [errorsAPI, setErrorsAPI] = React.useState<ISigninErrors>({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);

  // Dialog
  const handleDialogOpen = () => {
    setDialogOpen(true);
  };
  const handleDialogClose = () => {
    setDialogOpen(false);
  };

  // Form
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm<ISigninForm>();
  const submitForm = (data: ISigninForm) => {
    signinUser(data, dispatch, handleDialogClose);
  };

  return (
    // HTML content 
  );
}

export default withRouter(Signin);
```

**Solution:**
I had the solution in front of me this whole time, but I was not using the function in the right way.

```
const state = useSelector((state: StoreState) => state);
```

This is called inside the Signin function component. Then when I am returning the HTML object, I just call

```
 {state.UI.errors !== null && 'general' in state.UI.errors && (
              <p>{state.UI.errors.general}</p>
            )}
```

Comment: useSelector should do the job. Every time one of your reducers get updated, it’ll trigger a new render on your component. Have you console.log the result of state.UI.errors in your component after you signed in?

Comment: If I cal useSelector inside `submitForm()` I get "React Hook "useSelector" is called in function "submitForm" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function"

Comment: If I call `useSelector()` outside `submitForm()`, then its values never change after `signinUser()` change the redux state.

Comment: @FedericoAlecci you were right, I was just using the variable in a wrong way. Now it works, thanks!